# Wordpress Plugin that creates a .json file

Tags: wordpress

I am currently creating a Wordpress plugin that reads the SQL tables of that site and converts them to JSON format.

I am also able to output that data in the said plugin's admin page. However, I am unable to enter that data into a .json file and have it downloaded. Basically this file won't run:

```
file_put_contents("$db.json", json_encode($import));
```

I was given a few hints:

Add the following headers:

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.json\"");
```

However, I cannot do that as it gives me the error that I cannot add additional headers after the initialization process ends (HTML is loaded onto the page).

Is anyone able to give me some direction on this issue?

High overview is:

1. Plugin is downloaded.
2. Users provide the username/password and database name in order to gain access to the SQL tables (via a form).
3. Submit form which runs a script once the form is submitted with that data a script uses it to spit out a JSON file.

Should you need additional information, please ask.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do for this is to create a separate PHP file that just returns the JSON content when invoked (for users logged in as an administrator, or with a certain capability). If you just want to access the WordPress database, and not some other database, you do not even need to ask for the database credentials. You could create a file called `export.php` inside your plugin's directory (e.g., if your plugin is named `my-plugin`, it would be `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/export.php`):

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
global $wpdb; // in case you need the WP database to query stuff

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.json"');

if(current_user_can('administrator')) {
    // use $wpdb to query the WP database?
    $result = ["result" => ["data" => "here"]];
} else {
    $result = [];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Replace the line with "result data here" with your own desired JSON result content, whatever it is.

Instead of requiring 'administrator' capabilities, you can also make it depend on any other privileges. If you do not want to use WP roles / capabilites, there are other means for access control mechanisms.

Next, you can create a form in your admin page that places the appropriate URL to your `export.php` like this:

```
        <form name="export" action="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)?>export.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download">
        </form>
```

Clicking on Download will fire the Request to export.php, which then starts the file download. No need for any further input fields, unless you want them there. For `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');`, the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` makes sure it is invoked from the root folder of your WP installation. `wp-load.php` loads the entire WordPress core including the `wp-config.php` settings, WP database connection, and plugins, so you could in theory use the entire plug-in API in `export.php` (in case the site would be using ACF, for example).

Comment: Hi Damocles,

A few questions about your answer... as I am not able to get the appropriate results.

a) wp-load.php is a file that allows access to the database (I see one named as such in the root folder)?
b) When I submit the form, I get the error that the Object Not Found. Since this is a plugin and will be moved from site to site, I do not think I have access to the root folder (and it doesn't work even if I put it there). What are your thoughts there?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi. wp-load.php is the file loading up the entire WordPress core. This is usually done by WP itself - whenever you're viewing the site or anything in wp-admin, it is already loaded. For PHP files anywhere inside the WordPress directory that you want to directly call by URL, e.g. `https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/export.php`, you must make the WP core load manually (by requiring wp-load.php) - only then you can use its features like API and database.
I've adapted my example so you can put `export.php` inside your plugin folder so it's shipped with the plugin.

Comment: Answer is correct and returns the appropriate results.

However, one adjustment I had to make (out of sheer coincidence it worked):

action="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'export.php'?>"

Moved the entire path inside the PHP tags.

Comment: Glad it worked :) Just one comment: that wasn't sheer coincidence for it to work. The `export.php` trailing the `plugin_dir_url()` path is a fixed string, so it can both be echo'ed, or just hardcoded right after the closed `<?php ?>` tag - will result in the same exact HTML output. The result is either (part within square brackets output by echo, text outside as regular output) "[...example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/export.php]" vs. "[...example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/]export.php". The client's browser will never know the difference in the end.